# How to handle year and month drop-downs using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone guide me, how to select a year and month drop-down using Java in Selenium?

Had used the code mentioned below, But it didn't work.

Java Code:

```
{
List<WebElement> NomDOBYear =  driver.findElements(By.className("ui-datepicker-year"));
Select selectYear= new Select((WebElement) NomDOBYear);
selectYear.selectByVisibleText("1991");


WebElement NomDOBMonth = (WebElement) driver.findElements(By.className("ui-datepicker-year"));
Select selectMonth= new Select(NomDOBMonth);
selectMonth.selectByVisibleText("Nov");
}
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Does the webpage use kendo-UI ?

Comment: If it is Kendo-UI then traditional 'Select' class of selenium wont work. You have to work with JavaScriptExecutor class.

Comment: @Ravi :- it is throwing error

Comment: @AritroSen :- It is working fine for other drop-downs but not working for date picker. How do I know which UI is it using?

Comment: @Anjita Please share the exception stacktrace and element tag, if the page is available in public domain please share the link, else please share the tag

Comment: we.tl/t-rCDJ600Ozn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

> driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-year"));

instead of

> driver.findElements(By.className("ui-datepicker-year"));

When you use driver.findElements(By.className("ui-datepicker-year")) you are storing return elements in a list(I am expecting that there are 2 or more elements with the same className as "ui-datepicker-year").
So, if that is the case then you should note that the constructor "Select" class of selenium takes a 'WebElement' as a parameter which can be the first or any element stored inside the list.
Then your code should be written like -

```
List<WebElement> NomDOBYear =  driver.findElements(By.className("ui-datepicker- 
year"));
Select selectYear= new Select(NomDOBYear.get(0));//first element of the list
selectYear.selectByVisibleText("1991");


WebElement NomDOBMonth = driver.findElement(By.className("ui- 
datepicker-month"));// you got the class name wrong here
Select selectMonth= new Select(NomDOBMonth);
selectMonth.selectByVisibleText("Nov");
```

Otherwise if there is only 1 element with className "ui-datepicker-year" or "ui-datepicker-month" in the entire DOM then your code should be written like -

```
WebElement NomDOBYear =  driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-year"));
Select selectYear= new Select(NomDOBYear);
selectYear.selectByVisibleText("1991");


WebElement NomDOBMonth = driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-month"));
Select selectMonth= new Select(NomDOBMonth);
selectMonth.selectByVisibleText("Nov");
```

I would still recommend using XPath for finding elements.